# Проверьте, пожалуйста, выделенное предложение - это дополнительное придаточное?

Tags: синтаксис

*Вполне вероятно, **что он не успеет прийти вовремя**.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

1) Вполне вероятно, что он не успеет прийти вовремя. **Это классическое изъяснительное придаточное с характерными для этого вида признаками:** опорное слово с модальным значением (нужно, возможно, нельзя, желательно) и союзная связь  (союз ЧТО) при отсутствии указательного слова (оно не является обязательным).

Такие придаточные **нужно отличать от двух других видов:**

**а) вмещающие СПП (приместоименные  изъяснительные придаточные)** с **обязательным указательным местоимением**, содержание которого раскрывает придаточное: Весь вечер он занимался ремонтом машины. - Весь вечер он занимался тем, что ремонтировал машину. Здесь также **союзная** связь.

б) **местоименно-определительные придаточные (связь местоименная!), указательное слово соотносится с союзным словом**:

**подлежащного типа**: Кто смел, тот уверен в себе.То, что случилось, не повторится.

**сказуемостного типа**: Каково лето, таково и сено. Я всё тот же, какой был.

**объектного типа (дополнительные придаточные)**: Я сказал то, что все давно знали. Нельзя найти то, чего нет. Не видим мы того, что видно ясно.

Comment: Sibylla, а разве дополнительные придаточные и изъяснительные придаточные не то же самые? Придаточными дополнительными  обычно называют в школьной практике.

Comment: В школе - да, там изъяснительные придаточные называют дополнительными,   в вузовской же грамматике этот термин не используется вообще. Мне он кажется неточным, так как в позиции дополнения могут выступать  придаточные разной структуры. Огорчает то, что в школе нет деления придаточных на два разные класса: с местоименной и союзной связью. Отсюда все школьные классификации упрощенные и не всегда ясные.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас выделено придаточное изъяснительное. Его редко называют дополнительным.

См.: [**Придаточные дополнительные (изъяснительные)**](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/738-222_pridatochnye_dopolnitelnye_izyasnitelnye.html).

Answer (score 1):

> *Вполне вероятно, **что он не успеет прийти вовремя.***
>
> Выделенное предложение - это дополнительное придаточное?

Нет, **не дополнительное**. Это придаточное замещает позицию отсутствующего подлежащего в главном предложении и потому может быть названо **придаточным подлежащным.** Так подобные придаточные назывались в прошлом, так их называют иногда и сейчас.  Но всё же **чаще** такие придаточные в настоящее время в большинстве  учебных пособий  рассматриваются как **придаточные изъяснительные**.

**Чаще**, но не везде… И если в пособии, по которому Вы, **Anonym,** занимаетесь, принята **классическая (традиционная)** классификация придаточных предложений, то и отвечать на вопрос о типе придаточного в приведённом в Вашем вопросе предложении нужно, думаю, используя термины именно  этой классификации.

Из **Бабайцевой** *("Анализ слова и предложения", М., 2014):*

> В **классической (традиционной)** классификации придаточные
>   соотносятся с членами предложения. При этом выделяются придаточные
>   **подлежащные, сказуемные, дополнительные, определительные** и **обстоятельственные** (места, времени, причины, следствия, образа действия и степени, сравнения, цели, условия, уступки). Особо
>   выделяются придаточные **присоединительные...**

Повторю ещё раз: в  предложении *"Вполне вероятно, что он не успеет прийти вовремя"* придаточное, на мой взляд, не дополнительное.  ПОДЛЕЖАЩНОЕ. Почему так?

Ещё раз обращусь к **Бабайцевой** *("Синтаксис русского языка", М., 2015):*

> **Придаточные подлежащные** отвечают на грамматические вопросы подлежащего (**кто? что?**): ***Что*** назначено судьбой, обязательно
>   **случится**.
>
> К главному предложению подлежащные придаточные прикрепляются союзными
>   словами *кто, что* и др., союзами *что, будто, чтобы* и др.
>
> В подлежащных придаточных раскрывается содержание местоимений, которые
>   в составе главного предложения выполняют функцию подлежащего…
>
> **В главном предложении может отсутствовать местоимение-подлежащее. В этом случае придаточное дополняет главное, занимая позицию
>   подлежащего:**
>
> *Чудится мне, **будто** песню печальную мать надо мною поёт в полусне. Необходимо, **чтобы** искусство не отставало от науки. Как хорошо,
>   **что** вы приехали вовремя.*

Похожи приведённые Бабайцевой примеры на разбираемый нами? По-моему, вполне.